# Swift strictness

Tags: swift

Well, it says on their website that Swift is a strict language. However, I am not sure in what ways it is considered to be strict. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: If you get out of line, it spanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements about the nature of Swift are often expressed in terms meaningful to people accustomed to the previous language, Objective-C. So in this case, the statement that Swift is "strict" typically refers to how things like variables are *typed*. But unless you have used another language like Objective-C or Ruby that is *not* strict about typing, you probably won't appreciate the difference.

For example, in Objective-C, programmers often use "dynamic typing", where a variable is typed as `id` and you can assign to it a value of *any* type, even different types at different times — now an NSString, now an NSNumber, now a UIView. But in Swift you can't do that; once we've established that this variable is a String, its value can only *ever* be a String.

Similarly, in Objective-C, NSArray is just "a collection of objects" of any old type. But in Swift, an Array is a collection of just *one* type of object and you have to say in advance exactly what type it is.

Comment: I think that another important point is the idea of "optionals", isn't it?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, Swift is somehow similar to Java in strictness?